# Excel Conditional formatting c# based on value from database

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to put some conditional formatting into C# code based on values I enter in a cell. The value I enter into the cell (a price) needs to be parsed into a method and this method assigns a value of 1 or 0 to a variable if it exists in the database.

I have the following `C#` loop:

```
//for each item in column AH - 
//  parse value into priceladdercheck method. 
//  If output variable returns 1 then leave it 
//  otherwise set cell colour to cyan.

public static void Worksheet_Change(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Target)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents = false;
    Range rangeAH = uiWorksheet.get_Range("AH:AH");

    foreach (Range cell in rangeAH.Cells)
    {
        PriceLadderCheck(cell.Value2);

        if (priceLadderCheck == 0)
        {
            cell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
        }
    }

    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents = false;
}
```

I need to put this in using conditional formatting as the user can put in values in column 'AH' at any time. Once they do I need it to call the above method `PriceLadderCheck`. I tried using the `worksheet_change` event but this doesnt get fired. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error or what is the issue you're having?

Comment: When the excel sheet loads there are no values in 'AH' so it tries to parse in cell.Value2 into the  method which calls a DB prcedure but its an empty cell so doesnt work. The user types the valus into AH after and if it exists then it should set colour

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking... Do you want to know how to check for an empty value?

Comment: I load excel and its populated loads of columns. Two columns are empty cells. When I type a value in one of those cells - The value I type in I want to check it against the database to see whether it exists in a database table. if it does not i want to set the background colour of a cell purple. I guess the issue is the formatting is not firing when i type a value in the cell. Does this make sense?

Comment: So you're saying that you want to run this code whenever a user changes a cell? Then you should look into the [Excel.Application.SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sheetchange) event.

Comment: This is VBA - I need it in c#

Comment: The language you use doesn't matter, it's part of the Excel.Application scope. Also you never said if you're doing this in a WPF/WinForms/Console application or as a VSTO so I can only guess which interfaces you're using.

Comment: I tried using worksheet_change but cant get it to work. Please see updated question. Also its VSTO